# How to display my view controller as ui pop over controller?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uipopovercontroller

```
- (IBAction)barBtnMenu:(id)sender
{
    menuVC *menu=[[menuVC alloc]init];
    UIPopoverController *popover =[[UIPopoverController alloc]initWithContentViewController:menu];
    popover.delegate=self;
    self.popOverController=popover;
    popover.popoverContentSize = CGSizeMake(150,200);
    [self.popOverController presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:barBtnItem permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
}
```

but its display plain pop up view ,but that menuVC have some data ,whats wrong in my code please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try to setup the frame of menuVC? Check this code

```
- (IBAction)barBtnMenu:(id)sender
{
    menuVC *menu=[[menuVC alloc]init];
    CGRect frame = menu.view.frame;
    frame.size = CGSizeMake(150,200);
    menu.view.frame = frame;
   UIPopoverController *popover =[[UIPopoverController alloc]initWithContentViewController:menu];
   popover.delegate=self;
   self.popOverController=popover;
   popover.popoverContentSize = CGSizeMake(150,200);
   [self.popOverController presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:barBtnItem permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: if i use story board segue->pop over its working. how to give that as programatically ..

Comment: but i didn't mentioned any thing inside the menuVC file.

Comment: is your menuVC in storyboard or programmatically?
If its from storyboard, then load it from storyboard like this:
menuVC = [self.storyboard instanitateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"yourMenuVCID"];

Comment: storyboard bro @hossam

Comment: when we click the bar button item ,then the another view controller have to display like a popovercontroller ...how i have to do that via programatically.

Comment: its working in ipad storyboard...,but not in the iphone story board.

Comment: its going to homeVC not like popovercontroller

Comment: You have to present it modally